# bluetooth device emulator for windows or android

Tags: bluetooth, android-emulator

My device has spec that can pair with 3 bluetooth devices only.

but i have only one pysical bluetooth device to pair with it.

is there emulator that i can mock up more devices and paired with the real device?

It would be good if it can be triggered from windows 10 or android phone.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "emulator" but there are lot of software that can be run on cells/PCs for Bluetooth communication testing. However it depends on your device requirements but any wait yo ucan use any number of cells to just pair with your device.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko not for bluetooth communication test. but setting up emulator to act as new bluetooth device for pairing purpose. as i don't have pysical device.

Comment: Got it now. Its not a problem actually cause you can run any Bluetooth demo application that can handle pairing requests on PC. Even 32Feet is OK with their samples.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko thanks i have take a look 32feet and that is not actually what i wanted. i need device emulator and my real device can do pairing with, perhaps some kind of desktop application software i can install.

Comment: The only way to get exactly device emulator is to contact device's developer.